# Bootstrap 4 grid not correctly aligning up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a grid system with Bootstrap 4 that stays inside one row if possible, but the way I'm trying to get it to align up isn't working.

It currently looks like this:

[image]

And this is what I'm trying to make:

[image]

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="card"><div class="card-block">This is some text within a card block.</div></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="card"><div class="card-block">This is some text within a card block.</div></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="card"><div class="card-block">This is some text within a card block.</div></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="card"><div class="card-block">This is some text within a card block.</div></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="card"><div class="card-block">This is some text within a card block.</div></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="card"><div class="card-block">This is some text within a card block.</div></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="card"><div class="card-block">This is some text within a card block.</div></div></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do in this case is to just add the class `offset-sm-6` to the 4th div like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="card"><div class="card-block">This is some text within a card block.</div></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="card"><div class="card-block">This is some text within a card block.</div></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="card"><div class="card-block">This is some text within a card block.</div></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 offset-sm-6"><div class="card"><div class="card-block">This is some text within a card block.</div></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="card"><div class="card-block">This is some text within a card block.</div></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="card"><div class="card-block">This is some text within a card block.</div></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="card"><div class="card-block">This is some text within a card block.</div></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That offset class will push (offset) the 4th div to the right by 6 units i.e. the size of the other div. And `sm` in the offset class means: That offset will only kick in on screens that small (`sm`) or larger but not on the smallest screens.

Comment: Thank you very much, much appreciated, this is perfect!